# How could I read a locally stored database (.db filetype) with an HTML file, WITHOUT using jQuery, Node.js, or any external library?

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql, database

Struggling with a Master's degree assignment. Essentially, a user enters a value into an 'ID' field, and after clicking on a button, the corresponding row appears from a database (.db filetype, saved locally). I understand how I can use divs and alter HTML to present the information, but I don't have any idea how to access the Database in an HTMl file. I know that once it's stored, it can be read with SQL commands... though I've never done this before, and have no idea what the syntax would be.
I've attached my current code from the assignment below - if anyone has any insight or references related to the issue, I'd appreciate the help a ton!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Access Database</title>
      <style>
    table {
      font-family: arial, sans-serif;
      border-collapse: collapse;
      width: 50%;
        margin: 10px auto;
    }

    td, th {
      border: 1px solid #dddddd;
      text-align: left;
      padding: 8px;
    }

    tr:nth-child(even) {
      background-color: #dddddd;
    }
          
    input
          {
              margin: 10px auto;
          }
          
    </style>
          
   <script>

        // Access Database here
       function searchDatabase()
       {
           // select firstname, lastname, country from users where id = document.getElementById('crit').value; //(?)
           return false;
       }
       
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>     
          
        <input name="crit" type="number" value="1"/>      
       <button id="search" onclick="searchDatabase()">Search</button>
        
        <table>
          <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>F Name</th>
            <th>Surname</th>
            <th>Country</th> 
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Foo</td>
            <td>Bar</td>
            <td>Canada</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should be able to make a `XMLHttpRequest` and specify your local file (I think it will only work on a server). It might be simpler to read the file in PHP

Comment: db operations require a server side programming language. You either submit a form to server or make an ajax request with javascript to send user input. There are storage facilities client side that can be used also but not to read/write to  `.db` file

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Client-side_web_APIs/Client-side_storage is probably worth reading for your scenario.